# routes in codeigniter/pyrocms

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, pyrocms

I saw this route I downloaded from sample module at pyrocms

```
$route['sample(/:num)?'] = 'sample/index$1';
```

I tried to removed the `'$1'` above and the site runs smooth. I am wondering what's that for, and can I remove it.

Comment: explain perfectly your question

Answer (score 1):

`$1` would be whatever matched by `(:num)` group - which is, really, any valid numbers. Whatever you add will get passed as the parameter for view method in pages controller. for example

```
$route['sample(/:num)?'] = 'sample/index/$1';
```

now in sample controller

```
function index($id){
   // $id something that matched by group (:num)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$1` in the sense anything comes dynamically after the url `sample/index`